# JSON array iteration: How to apply a function on each element of a json array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

I'm trying to apply a javascript method f(x,y) on each element of a JSON array.

This is my code example:

```js
var jsonData = {"a":[1900,1910,1920,1930],"b":[12,19,8,55]}

for (var i=0; jsonData.a.length; i++){
  f(jsonData.a[i],jsonData.b[i])
}
```

Is it wrong what I'm doing? The code is not working..

Comment: "not working" means what?

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: yes, invalid end condition. silly bug.. thx all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code goes into an infinite loop. Change it to

```
for (var i=0; i < jsonData.a.length; i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the loop when to stop.

Change this:

```
for (var i=0; jsonData.a.length; i++){
```

To this:

```
for (var i=0; i < jsonData.a.length; i++){
```

Comment: oops :) diodn't saw that!.. thx

Answer (score 1):

the thing is that you are running into infinite loop.

you have not specified any terminating condition in `for` loop

```
var jsonData = {"a":[1900,1910,1920,1930],"b":[12,19,8,55]}

for (var i=0; i < jsonData.a.length; i++){
  f(jsonData.a[i],jsonData.b[i])
}
```

this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your for-loop has an invalid condition. It should be:

```
var jsonData = {"a":[1900,1910,1920,1930],"b":[12,19,8,55]}

for (var i=0; i < jsonData.a.length; i++){
    f(jsonData.a[i],jsonData.b[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is checking "jsonData.a.length", which is always true because it's evaluating a positive integer. You could write your loop with `for (var i=0; i < jsonData.a.length; i++) {...}` or, better yet, use the "for in" loop: `for (var i in jsonData.a) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
var forEach=Function.prototype.call.bind([].forEach)
var jsonData = {"a":[1900,1910,1920,1930],"b":[12,19,8,55]}
function print(x,y){
    console.log(x+":"+y);
}
forEach(jsonData.a, function(o,i){
    print(o,jsonData.b[i]);
});
```

And a JSFiddle to play around: http://jsfiddle.net/sG5st/